# Rails 4 - Strong Params - white labelling foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, strong-parameters

I have a rails 4 app.

When creating permitted params in a controller where there is a belongs_to association with another model, do you need to include the foreign key in the permitted params, so that it can be updated when the record is saved, or is that automatic?

Comment: you should permit it, unless you are using nested forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **NOT** automatic.

In Rails 4, you have to permit the attribute in order to be able to mass assign its value. The foreign key of the other model is an attribute of your current model that you're trying to update. Without permitting that, you can't update it's value.

Answer (score 0):

The *foreign key* is not automatic, [the *associated object* is](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to):

[image]

This means the following is true:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @item = Item.new new_params
      @associated = Associated.find x

      @item.associated = @associated #-> this always works & will save 
      @item.save
   end

   private

   def new_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :etc) #-> foreign_key would have to be explicitly defined here if associated_id was passed from a form
   end
end
```

This should give you some perspective on what you can do with your objects.

---

**Update**

If you want to assign a post to the current user each time, you'd be able to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @post = Post.new post_params
      @post.user = current_user # -> however you identify the user
      @post.save
   end
end
```

Comment: Hi Rich, but the comment in your params def is my confusion. I don't ask users to pass their id in the form. That's why I thought it should not be whitelisted.

Comment: If you wanted to explicitly define `x_id` in your model, you'd have to permit the params for it. If you wanted to populate the associated object (IE people cannot change it), you'll be able to do it as above

Comment: I'm afraid I'm confused by that statement as well. If there is a user model and a posts model, users can create posts, Posts belongs to User. Does post  params method have to have a user id key in it - if the posts form does not ask for a field where the user enters their user id?

Comment: Okay let me explain clearer. If a post belongs to a user, you can use my code above to populate the user in the controller. The params are only required if you want your users to pick the `user_id` for the post.

Comment: but does the reference to ':etc' in the params definition mean the that the etc includes the foreign key if the user is going to create a post?

Comment: Sorry - I used `:etc` as a filler; I didn't know your attributes. You need to include each of your attributes in the `permit()` method

Comment: ok but one attribute is the foreign key. I want to figure out whether the whitelisting is required for the belongs to relationship